# WooCommerce displays upsale products in random order, not in the order they were registered

Tags: woocommerce

The up-sell products on a single product page are rendered in random order, not in the order  they were registered in the admin interface.

The desired functionality is the same order as in the admin interface, so how should one accomplish that in the quickest way?

Answer (score 4):

In the functions-file, do the following:

1. Remove the "original" upsale display

   ```
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woo_wc_upsell_display', 15 );
   ```
2. Add custom upsell display ordered by the order you've added the products in the admin interface

   ```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_upsell_display', 15 );

   if (!function_exists('custom_wc_upsell_display')) {
       function custom_wc_upsell_display() {
           woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product/up-sells.php', array(
               'posts_per_page'  => -1,
               'orderby'    => 'post__in',
               'columns'    => 3
           ));
       }
   }
   ```

What actually happens is that in the up-sells template the args-array is complemented with various other arguments (like post_type etc), and one of these arguments is the `post__in` argument. The template already makes use of a function that fetches the up-sales product IDs in the correct order, and this array of ID's is then used to limit the result by using the `post__in` argument.

The trick is to use this already existing information. By setting the `orderby` argument to `'post__in'`, the query will honor the order given in the `post__in` argument!